# Out of memory error from PHP simplexml_load_string()

Tags: php, iis, memory-limit, simplexml

I have php 5.3.28 on windows IIS. I use XLSXReader class to upload excel files. When I upload an excel with more than 130k rows, I got a out of memory error:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]:
>   Entity: line 2: parser error : out of memory error in
>   C:\www\class\XLSXReader.php on line 158

**php.ini configuration**

```
memory_limit = 128000M
post_max_size = 800M
```

**.htaccess configuration**

```
php_value memory_limit 12800M
RLimitMem 128000000
```

I forced everything as much as possible but I still got the error. Do you have any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Dont try it read file completly try to read it chuncks

Comment: I use this class and I dont know how to read in multible times with this library; https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsx/blob/master/src/SimpleXLSX.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function is the best way to parse large files

> **XMLReader and SimpleXMLElement**
>   for more information : [enter link description here](http://drib.tech/programming/parse-large-xml-files-php)